# Gravitational Fields

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

I've been trying to understand a bit more about how gravitational fields work.

I am trying to understand what would happen in the following hypothetical situation: astronauts are on the moon, and unlike reality, the gravitational force of Earth on the moon at the moon is stronger than the surface gravity of the moon. Would the astronauts slowly drift back to Earth, or would they stay on the moon due to its centripetal acceleration?

Comment: This answer is not correct, as the hog parameter is not the force but the acceleration  and also because the so called centrifugal force must be taken into account. Both grabity and centrifugal forces are proportional to mass, so the same equations apply for both moon and astronaut. What is true is the final equation if M is earth' mass and r=d= earth-moon distance. Hence @Bowlofred answer is the good one.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what happens to the moon?  The moon is in orbit around the earth.  The earth's pull changes its direction, but doesn't (dramatically) bring it closer to the earth.

If the moon had little or no surface gravity, then an astronaut nearby would be in the same situation: in orbit around the earth.  Even without the pull from the moon, they would be in no danger of crashing into the earth.   This is the exact situation with astronauts around the space station.  The station has only a tiny gravitational pull, but astronauts outside are not yanked down to earth.  Both they and the station are accelerated by the same amount, so remain close to each other.

Answer (score 0):

No. As you may know, gravitational force is inversely proportional to the square of distance apart and directly proportional to both masses. Since an astronaut is rather a really small mass relative to a planetary scale, the force on the astronaut by earth is much less than the force of the moon on the astronaut. The astronaut is much closer to the center of the moon than that of the earth, so the astronaut is more or less stuck to the moon, and they're both considered a single mass by another external gravitational field. Even in a case where the gravitational force is so strong, the moon itself would rather be pulled to crash with the planet along with the astronaut attach to it unless the angular/instantaneous velocity of the moon plus astronaut is high enough.
Given by:
$$G\frac {Mm}{d^2} = \frac {mv^2}{r}$$